# Magento :: Categories and Subcategories

Tags: php, sql, css, magento, multiple-databases

Please anyone can help me how to design category and subcategory listing as below
http://www.officemax.com.au/office-supplies/writing.html

PS:: Magento default design is  when you click a category it will list all products in that category straight. What I really want to do is , it should list all the subcategories first in the page like the above sample site  http://www.officemax.com.au/office-supplies/writing.html and then list all relevent products of that subcategories

I will greatly appreciate if some one can help me.

Answer (score 1):

### Sub Categories within Categories - This is sample, you should customize

1.- Create a page called *subcategory.phtml* in the *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation* folder and add following code piece :

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories(); ?>
<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
<?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

2.- Create a static block called "MySubcategory" and put the following code into content :

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation"  template="catalog/navigation/subcategory.phtml"}}
```

3.- Now go to category which you would like to use to show sub categories and ensure that category not set as an "*anchor*". In the display option tab, set it to show as "*Static Block Only*" and choose the block "*MySubcategory*"

Answer (score 0):

Use Easy Catalog Images module: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/module/1562/magento-easy-catalog-images